# security.ubuntu.com repository doesn't have a release file

Tags: package-management, updates, 20.04, ppa, software-sources

Output of `sudo apt update` in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Hit:3 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease        
Hit:4 http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease      
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release 404 Not Found [IP: 110.44.112.44 80]
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease

Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list` and Software & Updates doesn't have this ppa.

Comment: Hmmm. It does indeed have a release file. I just checked - it's there. Please [edit your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1244751/edit) to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two PPAs in your software sources appear to be updating normally, but a temporary glitch in your software repository server has caused http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security to be disabled.

If you ignore the `E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security Release' does not have a Release file.` error message the disabled repository will come back by itself. It could come back in a day, a few days or maybe even a month, but it will come back by itself eventually.

Meanwhile your system will be able to update normally except for updating packages from the disabled repository.

Comment: Okay, this makes a lot of sense. I thought something was broke in my system and tried different things. Thanks!

Comment: If you're worried about it you can disable the `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security` repository, but it is a security repository and if you disable it now you might forget to re-enable it later on. On the other hand it could come back by itself in a day, a few days or maybe even a month, but it will come back by itself eventually.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me because of some icon packages that weren't in my software updates server. I ignored the error messages and the repository eventually came back by itself.